# Restart Pi after ping failure?

Tags: ethernet, cron, services, crash, watchdog

I have been creating a prototype using Pi Zeros, they work great at my house but are failing often at customer's site (other side of country).

I do not know if the Pi kernel is crashing or if it's ethernet related.

I have isolated things such as a deticated network, high end power supplies, sd cards but the same issues keeps causing the pi to crash after ~1day.

When the crash occurs I must call customer and ask them to power cycle the device.

*I am currently configuring watchdog timer to reset after kernel crash.*

But if it is a faulty ethernet driver then what would be a simple (reliable) way to also reset the pi if the ethernet becomes unreachable and/or it can no longer ping the main server?

I could imagine using cron so the pi will attempt to ping the main server every 30 seconds, but I don't know of any method to initiate a restart after ping fails a couple times in a row, and I would love to hear if anyone can suggest some approaches?

Thank you

Comment: not likely to be `ethernet related` - since the zero has no ethernet

Comment: I have added a NIC.

Comment: you may want to add some **details** about the external device if that is the cause of the failure then :p

Comment: `any method to initiate a restart` - there's a command called `reboot` - that should do it - or you could `ifdown eth0; sleep 1; ifup eth0` - see if that brings things up again

Comment: Cool idea about restarting eth0, but what is easy way to connect `reboot` to a sequence of failed ping? Use cron? SH script? Write a service?

Comment: well, you'll want to check periodically, but is every minute often enough? if you need more often then cron is out

Comment: I'd be tempted to write something that keeps a permanent connection to your main server ... when the connection is closed, try to open the connection again - if that fails, determine if the failure is at the pi end or the server end - if it's the pi end, do whatever is needed to fix the issue (reboot, or restart eth0) - if the issue is just with the server, then just keep trying to connect to the server without restart/reboot

Comment: Might be completely unrelated but I had a similar issue where all my Pi's where crashing once a day or every other day. When I looked into it it turned out to be the dhcp lease on the router. For some reason my default lease was 24hrs and then my router would disconnect all devices and attempt to reconnect them (not sure why, it's the ISP's own brand router so not the best, I can't look at many settings on it). In the end I upped the lease time to 7 days and haven't had any issues since. In the logs I kept seeing a crash at the time they went down where the connection suddenly dropped out.

Comment: Unfortunately all IPs are static and I have asked to customer to run ethernet lines from a dedicated switch to the device so to isolate the network from routers and unwanted traffic.

Comment: If pings get replies, then the $? variable equals 0. When replies don't show up, it will have a non-zero value.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a small bash script that you can call with cron, for example every 30 seconds.

```
#!/bin/bash

COUNT=3
INTERVAL=1

for ((i=COUNT; i>0; i--)); do
    /bin/ping -c1 -n 8.8.8.8 >/dev/null 2>&1
    [ $? -eq 0 ] && exit 0
    sleep $INTERVAL
done
/sbin/reboot
```

This will look $COUNT times if ping returns without error. If so the script exit immediately successful.

If ping fails $COUNT times in a row the script will reboot the RasPi.

Answer (score 0):

Look at Monit which can be configured to monitor and do many things and runs well on the Pi. I've been using it for years on mine.

Comment: This look really cool, but I can't tell if it could be configured to reboot the pi if the Ethernet becomes unresponsive. Not sure if there would be any services that fail or what it would look for. But network traffic to/from the device definitely does stop and any pings would fail during this time.